# How to stop a Python daemon thread with infinite loop at shutdown?

Tags: python, multithreading

Suppose I have something like this :

```
import threading
import time

_FINISH = False


def hang():
    while True:
        if _FINISH:
            break
        print 'hanging..'
        time.sleep(10)


def main():
    global _FINISH
    t = threading.Thread(target=hang)
    t.setDaemon( True )
    t.start()
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If my thread is daemon, do I need to have a global _FINISH to control exit clause of break loop? I tried and I don't seem to need it - when program exits ( in that case after the sleep ) then program terminates, which closes the thread too.

But I've seen that code too - is it just bad practise? Can I get away with no global flag for controlling the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: threading - Thread Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) (**emphasis** is mine):

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that **the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left**. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The flag can be set through the [daemon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) property or the *daemon* constructor argument.
>
> **Note**: **Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources** (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) **may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism** such as an [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event).

Per above, technically, you don't need the *_FINISH* logic, as the thread will end when the main one does. 
But, according to your code, **no one (main thread) signals that the thread should end** (something like `_FINISH = True`), so the logic in the thread is useless (therefore it can be removed). 
Also, according to the above recommendation, you should implement the synchronization mechanism between your threads, and avoid making them *daemon*s (in most of the cases).